# Javafx sortedlist with extractor

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a chat application with javafx. My contacts are displayed in ListView which is backed by sortedlist. I created my observable list with the extractor callback like this:

```
contacts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Callback<Contact, Observable[]>() {
        @Override
        public Observable[] call(Contact param) {
            return new Observable[]{param.getChat().lastMessageTimeDateProperty()};
        }
    });
filteredListOfContacts = new FilteredList<>(contacts);
sortedListOfContacts = new SortedList<Contact>(filteredListOfContacts, new ContactComparator());
```

the comparator i use is this:

```
@Override
public int compare(Contact o1, Contact o2) {
    if (o1 == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (o2 == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (o1.getChat().getMessages().isEmpty() && o2.getChat().getMessages().isEmpty()) {
        return o1.getUserName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getUserName());
    }
    if (o1.getChat().getLastMessageDateTime() == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (o2.getChat().getLastMessageDateTime() == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (o1.getChat().getLastMessageDateTime().isBefore(o2.getChat().getLastMessageDateTime())) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Whenever user gets new message from any user, corresponding chat's `lastMessageDateTime` is changed:

```
chat.setLastMessageDateTime(LocalDateTime.of(msg.getDate(), msg.getTime()));
```

However this method causes

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2
at javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList.findPosition(SortedList.java:318)
at javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList.update(SortedList.java:380)
at javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList.sourceChanged(SortedList.java:103)
at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList.lambda$getListener$15(TransformationList.java:106)
at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList$$Lambda$231/9978943.onChanged(Unknown Source)
at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:485)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.sourceChanged(FilteredList.java:147)
at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList.lambda$getListener$15(TransformationList.java:106)
at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList$$Lambda$231/9978943.onChanged(Unknown Source)
at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:485)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.access$200(ObservableListWrapper.java:45)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper$1$1.invalidated(ObservableListWrapper.java:75)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
```

I guess i am doing something wrong, could you please point to my mistake, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not the only one. Must be a bug, can you report it to Oracle?